# How to sort a query result by the result of a function in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

How does one sort a query result by the result of a function in mongoDB? In SQL i have the follow code:

```
select field1, 
       field2,
       myFunction(field1, 0)
from   myTable
where  field4 = 5
order  by 3
```

Comment: order  by 3 can you explain what reason of 3

Comment: to order the result by return of myFunction

Comment: This isn't currently possible within MongoDB itself

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you're trying to do. It'd be helpful if you provided more clarity. What will your function do? It's possible that the aggregation framework will do the trick. Otherwise, you can do a find, and process the sort via JavaScript or whatever language you have your app in.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal myFunction do a calculation with value of field param and returns a numeric value for each row, and i need to sort by this result.

Comment: What sort of value/calculation is done in your function? There isn't enough detail to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: could be a calculation of price, but what the function do is not relevant, the important is return that will be used to sort. Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create the function below (inside mongodb) like alternative for my sql query. May not be ideal, but solved my problem:

```
function() {
  var list = Array();
  // myColletion is myTable equivalent
  db.myCollection.find({ field4: 5}).forEach(
    function (vet) {
      list.push([  vet.field1,
                   vet.field2,
                   myFunction(vet.field1, 0)])
    }
  );
  list.sort(function(a,b){return ((a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : ((a[1] > b[1]) ? 1 : 0));});
  return list;
}
```